# Toggling an html IMG element's class using JS (no Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I give up... All of your answers were just different ways of targeting the local element.

If you bothered to actually read what I was saying you would realise that it was not a problem with the code I already had, just that the code DID NOT work on IMG tags.

While faffing around trying to demonstrate my problem (and that none of your solutions did anything different to what was already happening) I found that I can achieve exactly what I want by applying a Grayscale filter to a DIV element placed over each image. The mouseover event then triggers an opacity change in the DIV element.

It is a little heavier that I wanted but it answered my ACTUAL question. The answer being:

Yes, there probably is a way to toggle class of IMG tags. But no, I am probably not going to find it here without causing arguments or being told i'm using "bad code". So yes, it IS easier and more efficient to target DIV elements.

By the way, page load times are about how large data packages are. Larger data packages (images, html/css/js documents, etc) take longer to download and so the page takes longer to load. The website I am trying to create proves this thesis, I have an almost complete and (almost) fully functional website with loads of 'clever' little effects all under 20mb, about 15mb of which is images. This website is clean and simple, is hosted on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 (using Papaya) and loads almost instantly.

THIS is what I meant by "I want this to be VERY lite". Thank you all for your attempts to help, it's just a shame that I couldn't get anyone to understand what was going on.

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference whether it's a div or img element as far as referencing it from JS, but either way you don't need any JS for this, you can do hover effects with just CSS. Having said that, try `onClick="colorFunction(this)";`.

Comment: I would have thought the same, but apparently this just doesn't work with an IMG element. I will try to record what it going on and upload to YouTube or something, it's so strange!

I didn't know you could code mouseover transitional effects in CSS?

Comment: There's nothing magic about IMG elements. Forget YouTube, update your question to show your actual code (rather than that `onClick=...` part in isolation - it's that an attribute in your img tag, or...? And consider providing a demo of the problem at http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: The problem is not that it would work or wouldnt work on images, the reference you're passing to the onclick handler is faulty. The solution lies with finding out how to correctly pass the img element as an argument to the onclick function.

Comment: Automatically creating global variables out of elements that have an id attribute, is bad habit IE introduced (and some browser later on copied, for compatibility reasons) – but that doesn’t make it correct. So there _is_ no variable called `image1` available in your code, therefor `undefined` gets passed to your function – and so results in the error you’re seeing. You can either pass the element directly, using `<img onclick="colorFunction(this)">`, or you need to pass the id as a string value, and then use `document.getElementById` inside your function to get the reference to the element.

Comment: Right passing ' this ' in the onclick attribute is the solution, I was trying to remember what it was... jQuery makes you lazy lol.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the first comment above... Pass `this`.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `onClick` to image element you don't need to pass anything, you will receive `MouseEvent` which contains all information. You need `target` from event.

I suggest to not use `onClick` on element as it is not scalable, you have to add it to all elements. Better to add listener to wrapping/container element and then filter target by some attribute e.g `data-something` Please check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ps8Lfs97/)

So you have wrapping element and you images:

```
<div class="images-container">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" data-toggleable class="thumb-gray thumb-color" />
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" data-toggleable class="thumb-gray" />
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150" data-toggleable class="thumb-gray" />
</div>
```

and you attach listener to you **wrapping** element. It is best practice as you don't attach listeners to each element and same time you are able easily scale your solution

```
var imagesContainerEl = document.querySelector('.images-container');

imagesContainerEl.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    if (element.hasAttribute('data-toggleable')) {
      element.classList.toggle('thumb-color');
  }
});
```

The same code can be extended to support `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Check [fiddle2](https://jsfiddle.net/suy8t3on/). One function to rule them all and in the darkness bind them..

```
var imagesContainerEl = document.querySelector('.images-container');

imagesContainerEl.addEventListener('mouseover', onToggleImage);
imagesContainerEl.addEventListener('mouseout', onToggleImage);


function onToggleImage(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    if (element.hasAttribute('data-toggleable')) {
      element.classList.toggle('thumb-color');
  }
}
```

Also updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/La88skje/) which shows how to make image grayscale/color

Comment: This solution would apply the effect to ALL images in the image container at once (a DIV element). The code I have been using does the same thing and occupies less space (also looks cleaner and simpler).

That is not what I want to achieve. Please allow a few minutes I'm doing to show the problem I am having and THEN people can call me stupid or tell me i'm using "bad code", but only IF they can provide a better solution (that isn't the same thing in a different way).

Comment: This solution works for images, divs and whatever you want. I would argue about cleanness and simplicity but it is not the topic. And next time think about providing proper examples and explanation before asking question.

Comment: Unsure of what you mean by "proper examples". I tried to use JSFiddle to demonstrate my problem, copied and pasted the EXACT code I'm using into the relevant boxes and what do you know, the code works! I then try saving all pages and opening the gallery page in chrome, ie, firefox and safari, I'm getting the same problem as I was before. No effect and error messages in the console.

Furthermore I tried your "solution" which, as I stated, seemed to add the effect to ALL images inside the DIV wrapper. It could not distinguish between the images.

Comment: If you don't want to apply effect to ALL images then just remove `data-toggleable` from images which should not be affected. I've edited my answer and added new fiddle which show how to make grayscale/colorful pictures on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Is what you refer to in your question as

```
onClick="colorFunction(image1)"
```

an ***inline*** javascript event listener?

If so, try replacing it with:

```
onClick="colorFunction(this)"
```

and rewrite `colorFunction()` as:

```
function colorFunction(image) {
    image.classList.toggle('thumb-color');
}
```

Comment: Self-taught from internet, no clue what an "inline javascript event listener" is. I will try your suggestion and try to find out what you mean (lol).

Comment: Normally event listeners are functions you register dom elements to in the script part of your page/project like : <DOMelement>.addEventListener('click', function(event){}); The 'inline' version is the onclick="" attribute you're using in your html -> "inline". @100000011

Comment: This won't quite work. `this` won't be the element if you call `colourFunction()` like that.

Comment: Thanks, @nnnnnn, I'm less familiar with how _inline javascript_ works given that I'm used to only ever deploying `addEventListener` unobtrusively. Post updated.

Comment: @Tariq - no, it's okay, @nnnnnn was right. I updated the post after he commented. Before, it read: `onClick="colorFunction()"` and `this.classList.toggle('thumb-color');` (... which is what works if, rather than using inline event listeners, you add event listeners unobtrusively...)